# Difference between JOIN expressions in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to ask the difference between the following join expressions and in what conditions is Method 2 more preferred than Method 1.

You can imagine tables a, b and c to be CTEs for i.e. With a AS (xxxxx), b AS (xxxxx), and c AS (xxxxx).

**Method 1:**

```
Select
a.customerid,
b.customerage,
b.customermobile,
a.itemid,
c.itemname
from a 
LEFT JOIN b on 
a.customerid = b.customerid
LEFT JOIN c on
a.itemid = c.itemid
```

**Method 2:**

```
Select
a.customerid,
b.customerage,
b.customermobile,
a.itemid,
c.itemname
from ((( a 
LEFT JOIN b on 
(a.customerid = b.customerid))
LEFT JOIN c on
(a.itemid = c.itemid))
```

Comment: I think the queries are equivalent. You can verify that with [`EXPLAIN`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html), you should get same plans for both.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.  This structure:

```
from a left join
     b left join
     c
```

is exactly defined as

```
from (a left join
      b
     ) left join
     c
```

(I'm leaving out the `on` clauses to simplify the explanation.)

Note:  The order of evaluation is important for outer joins.  But even for inner joins, the above is subtly different from:

```
from a left join
     (b left join
      c
     )
```

For instance, this won't even parse if the `on` clause between `b` and `c` references `a` as well.